# Using Count and Group By on table field with "-"

Tags: mysql

I am running a query that currently counts `species` from `animals` table. However I am not getting the desired result with the query listed below. Currently the `COUNT` is counting number of `specie`, which is composed of two words `type` and `breed`(e.g. `dog-pitbull`). The query returns `1` for all entries. However, How could I group result and count by dogs,cats,birds, etc. disregarding breed? [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e961b/3)

Query

```
SELECT specie, COUNT(*) as Total FROM animals GROUP BY specie;
```

Schema

```
CREATE TABLE animals
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(20), `specie` varchar(55))
;

INSERT INTO animals
    (`id`, `name`, `specie`)
VALUES
    (1, 'dougie', 'dog-poodle'),
    (2, 'bonzo', 'dog-pitbull'),
    (3, 'cadi', 'cat-persian'),
    (4, 'mr.turtle', 'turtle-snapping'),
    (5, 'spotty', 'turtle-spotted'),
    (6, 'tweety', 'bird-canary')
;
```

Comment: Can you please show how do you like the final data set to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give you the animal type and the count i.e. 2 dog, 1 cat, 2 turtle, 1 bird.

It looks at the value of `specie` and it return the value before the 1st `-` found along with the count.

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(specie,'-',1) AS specie
, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM animals
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(specie,'-',1);
```

Answer (score 1):

USE SUBSTRING_INDEX:

```
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(specie,'-',1), specie, COUNT(*) AS Total 
FROM animals GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(specie,'-',1);


    RESULT:
        bird    bird-canary     1
        cat     cat-persian     1
        dog     dog-poodle      2
        turtle  turtle-snapping 2
```

DOKU SUBSTRING_INDEX